# FFI from MacRuby?

Tags: ruby, xcode, rubygems, ffi, macruby

I need to use a gem from MacRuby (ruby-keychain), and this gem uses FFI.

But it looks like FFI is not working from MacRuby.

Using the irb console, it works fine :

```
cobalt:~ charbon$ irb
irb(main):001:0> require 'ffi'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> module MyLib
irb(main):003:1>   extend FFI::Library
irb(main):004:1>   ffi_lib 'c'
irb(main):005:1>   attach_function :puts, [ :string ], :int
irb(main):006:1> end
=> #<FFI::Function address=0x007fff8be0197b>
irb(main):007:0> MyLib.puts 'Hello, World using libc!'
Hello, World using libc!
```

But as soon as i switch to the macirb console (the one provided by Macruby), it fails

```
cobalt:~ charbon$ macirb
irb(main):001:0> require 'ffi'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> 
=> nil
irb(main):003:0> module MyLib
irb(main):004:1>     extend FFI::Library
irb(main):005:1>     ffi_lib 'c'
irb(main):006:1>     attach_function :puts, [ :string ], :int
irb(main):007:0> end
NoMethodError: undefined method `ffi_lib' for MyLib:Class
```

The gem FFI is installed on the system

```
cobalt:~ charbon$ macgem list
*** LOCAL GEMS ***
corefoundation (0.1.4)
ffi (1.9.0)
ruby-keychain (0.1.1)
```

I've search all I could about that.

- https://github.com/MacRuby/MacRuby/blob/master/lib/ffi.rb says FFI is built into MacRuby
- found few posts on the net with same question but no answer  (just put one, not enough rep for more)
  https://github.com/kreynolds/phidgets-ffi/issues/4

Hope somebody can help ! I'm working with os X 10.8.3, ruby 1.9.3, macruby 1.9.2

Comment: Macruby's implementation of FFI lags behind what the MRI gem and jruby do unfortunately

Comment: What are you doing with `ffi`? The beauty of `macruby` is the ability to access static APIs, which means C functions, structures, opaque types.

Comment: in the very short term : trying to get ruby-keychain working. In the short term, use the class that seemed the most recent / complete. In the middle term, get a better understanding of macruby and external libraries. In the long term we'll all be dead (Keynes)

Comment: `ruby-keychain` is a wrapper for the OSX keychain. But, with `macruby`, there is no need for a wrapper. Keychain Services are directly accessible through the [Security framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Security/Reference/keychainservices/Reference/reference.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try the phidgets_native gem instead - there's no FFI requirement and it runs fine on OSX (In fact it was developed on it). It's newer, faster, and much more stable. (Plus it supports arm)

Comment: do you mean https://github.com/brighton36/phidgets_native ? "This library is a set of classes for use with the excellent USB sensing and controller devices available for sale on phidgets.com." ??

Comment: yep - that's the one. Hopefully that works for you. If not - let me know.

Comment: I d'ont understand how it's related to my question, which is about keychain wrappers & FFI